# Show all field in OneToOneField field type

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

In Django 1.8.3, I have following classes and they are showing in Admin Panel:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    address_line1 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address_line2 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address_line3 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address)
```

Now in Customer form in Admin Panel, the Address is shown as a dropdown menu. My question is: How can I show all fields of the Address class instead of a single dropdown in Customer form as it is a OneToOneField in Customer class?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would change the structure so that Address could be an inline. In the models.py:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Address(models.Model):
    costumer = models.OneToOneField(Costumer)
    address_line1 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address_line2 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address_line3 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

And then, in the admin.py:

```
class AddressInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Address
    extra = 1
    max_num = 1

class CostumerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AddressInline]


admin.site.register(Costumer, CostumerAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for field in YourModelClass._meta.get_fields():
    # iterate through main model's fields
    if isinstance(field, OneToOneField):
        # if the field is an OneToOneField
        for field2 in YourModelClass._meta.get_field(field.name).related_model._meta.get_fields():
            # iterate through the OneToOneField's fields
            fieldname = field2.name
            fieldvalue = field2.value_from_object(getattr(instance, field.name))
            # getattr simulates instance.`field.name`
    else:
        fieldname = field.name
        fieldvalue = field.value_from_object(instance)
```

where **YourModelClass** is the model that contains more ***OneToOneField*** objects and/or other basic models. In the example above, it is **Address**, and **instance** is the instance of the model.
Please notice you **don't need the instance** to get the field names, but you need it if you want to get the field value.
I use this code to convert an instance of a model into a context dictionary for dynamic settings, i'm not sure it's the best solution.